# Loop until the last column in a row and fill comboBox

Tags: excel, vba

How to fill my ComboBox1 with all the values of a row without blanks from B2 until the End of the row?

I know :

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A2:A" & .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

but this is the code to loop until the last row in a column, I want to do the opposite.

Comment: So you want to fill it with all the data in row 2, from column B til whatever column doesn't contain data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a variable (`LC`) to store the column index of your last used column for readability. You should also declare a `Worksheet` variable, or use a `With Block` to ensure all of your objects are properly qualified.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LC As Long

LC = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(2, LC)).[what?]
```

---

Here is how you could implement a `Column Loop`

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LC As Long

LC = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To LC
    If ws.Cells(2, i) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Blank Cell: " & ws.Cells(2, i).Address(False, False)
    Else
        MsgBox "Non-Blank Cell: " & ws.Cells(2, i).Address(False, False)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Probably the cleaner solution (storing a variable).

Comment: hi Urdeaboy thanks for your answer but how can I loop on every cell and check if it's blank or not, if it's not I'll add it to my combobox ?

Comment: Updated @xAminex

Comment: thanks urdearboy, I'll run the code and let you know. if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

Note - it looks like in your example you were using a `With` block - so add periods in front of all those cells to make sure your ranges are fully qualified.

Comment: +1 but also noting (for OP) that if you are using a `With` block, you can delete the `Sheets("Sheetname")` from your code unless its looking at a different sheet

Comment: Thanks - and I noticed that as well. Hard to tell what their intent is.

Answer (score 2):

## Fill Combo With Row (Resize Version)

### ActiveSheet

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   Const cStrFirst As String = "A2"           ' First Cell Range

   Dim vntRange As Variant                    ' Range Array
   Dim i As Integer                           ' Columns Counter

   vntRange = Range(cStrFirst).Resize(, Cells(Range(cStrFirst).Row, _
       Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)

   For i = 1 To UBound(vntRange, 2)
     If vntRange(1, i) <> "" Then
       ComboBox1.AddItem vntRange(1, i)
     End If
   Next

End Sub
```

### Any Sheet

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   Const cStrSheet As Variant = "Sheetname"   ' Sheet Name/Index
   Const cStrFirst As String = "A2"           ' First Cell Range

   Dim vntRange As Variant                    ' Range Array
   Dim i As Integer                           ' Columns Counter

   With Worksheets(cStrSheet)
     vntRange = .Range(cStrFirst).Resize(, .Cells(.Range(cStrFirst).Row, _
       .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
   End With

   For i = 1 To UBound(vntRange, 2)
     If vntRange(1, i) <> "" Then
       ComboBox1.AddItem vntRange(1, i)
     End If
   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dim xrow1 as long, xrow2 as long, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet1")
set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet2")
xrow2 = 2

for xrow1 = 2 to 65536
    if ws1.cells(xrow1, 1) = "" Then
    else
        ws1.cells(xrow1, 1).value = ws2.cells(xrow2, 1).value     
    end if
    xrow2 = xrow2 + 1
next xrow1
```

This would copy all the values in the first column of ws1 to ws2 and skip over all of the blank rows. I'm not familiar with the specific syntax for a combo box, but I assume if you altered my code slightly, you could make it work.

If you want me to code something specific to your project, let me see what you have written so far and/or some of the data you want transferred.

Comment: May I suggest swapping 65536 with a number better representing the last row? Also you could move `xrow2 = xrow2 + 1` outside of the `If` block, no need for the extra line :)

Comment: good point I fixed the latter.  I used 2 to 65536 because that was the range that OP used in his example.